# Autocompletion does not work for TexWorks editor on MacTex

Tags: mactex, texworks

I'm using TeXWorks (Version 0.6.8 ("github") [r.6b1c6ab, ]) with MacTex-2023 distribution on macOS Sonoma 14.2.1. Even after enabling autocompletion in TeXWorks preference the same is not triggered when I press the tab button.

I also tried scripting it following:

https://henrikmidtiby.github.io/texworksautocompletion/

where I kept the autocomplete directory at the following path: /Users/username/Library/Application Support/TUG/TeXworks/scripts/autocomplete

Upon relaunching TeXWorks, this does apper in the script directory. However, the trigger still does not take place. Am I missing something very basic?